# How to Find If ItemID have a different ItemCode in a list or array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

What i need here is i want to know If that ItemId has a Different ItemCode or not because in my project only One ItemId can Have one ItemCode but Location can be different as a much as can.
Is there any way i can solve  this?

Here is my Code:

```
Product[] products = { 
    new Product { ItemId= , 1001="apple", ItemCode=9, Location=store1 }, 
    new Product { ItemId= , 1001="apple", ItemCode=10, Location=store2 },
    new Product { ItemId= , 1002="apple", ItemCode=11, Location=store3 }, 
    new Product { ItemId= , 1002="apple", ItemCode=11, Location=store3 } 
};
```

Comment: What had you tried so far? ... also you List initialization code doesn't look valid

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that compiles. It is also unclear what you are asking. Do you want 1002 to be returned since it has two entries with the same `ItemCode`? If so, `products.GroupBy(z => new { z.ItemId, z.ItemCode}).Where(z => z.Count() > 1)` may get you started.

Comment: Sorry for the bad writing..but the thing is i want to show a Error if 'ItemId' has a two different 'ItemCode'

In my code 'ItemId' 1001 have two different 'ItemCode' (10&11) so i want to show a error because of that.

Note: One 'ItemId' should have one 'ItemCode'

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To collect items and their validity:

```
var itemsValidity = 
    products.GroupBy(p => p.ItemId).
             Select(g => new
             {
                 ItemId = g.Key,
                 IsValid = !g.GroupBy(item => item.ItemCode).Skip(1).Any()
             });
```

will return a collection of objects with ItemId and a flag indicating whether the ItemId is associated to more than one ItemCode.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TfeR0h)

Comment: @AdamTerry What do you mean it's not working? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @vc74 Sir what i want is if 'ItemId' 1001 have two different 'ItemCode' (10&11)  then to show a Error if 'ItemId' 1001 have same 'ItemCode' (10&10) or (11&11) then ok

Comment: @AdamTerry The linq query I wrote returns all the items, indicating whether each item is valid or not. If you want only the invalid items, you just have to add `.Where(item => !item.IsValid)`

Comment: @vc74 but sir for me Select seems not working..it didn't show my list data

Here is my list:  'List<ItemViewModel> ProcuctItems'

Comment: @AdamTerry I'm still not sure I understand your issue. Please try the fiddle code, it displays for each item ID whether it's valid (single item code) or not. Is it what you meant in your question?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help..i got it now..I am using a dictionary & it works :)